# Unity simple animation for every overridecontroller

Tags: unity-game-engine

Is there a way to use my animation that scales the sprite over time for every Overridecontroller/ spritesheet or do I have to reanimate the same animation for every spritesheet? It would work with code but can I do it in the unity editor anywhere?

Comment: Can please elaborate, on what you are saying. Give us some more information.

Comment: i have made an animation for my player with the record button. It's a simple animation which just increases transform scale of the sprite over time. I want to use this animation on every Skin in my game without animating it manually for every skin because its just those numbers that change the scaling. How can i achieve this? Do I have to write it in code or is there a possibility in the editor?

Comment: It totally depends on how you are animating your player and how you manager your skins. Ok try copying the Animator component from one skin to another skin, this should work. Otherwise animating the script itself animate the parent object of the sprite, and when you want to change the skin just change the sprite inside the Animated parent.

Comment: Did you found the solution of your problem.

Comment: yes it worked with animating a parent of my player. Thank you!